# AWS Amplify Storage module - Angular 6

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, angular6, aws-amplify

I'm in the process of developing a web application (using Angular6) that uses aws amplify.

The storage module provided by amplify lets you store your files in three protective levels (public, protected & private). I have a requirement to process an uploaded file via a lambda function.

My questions is whether the s3 buckets (and 'folders') created via the amplify available to Lambda functions (as the buckets are encrypted to use only via the app)??

would changing CORS on the S3 bucket do the trick?. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An S3 bucket that is created by Amplify CLI is like any other S3 bucket. You can access it provided that appropriate permissions are in place.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/set-permissions.html